# Inflate the actionbar from menu in tabhost activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabhost

In my app i inflate the action bar in Tabhost activity. Here actionbar dosn't displayed even i inflate using  `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`In follwing i have posted my code

TabhostActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/appblue">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

This is my menuItem.xml (Actionbar items)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:appmunu="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.after2.svirtzone.after2_gradle.UserDashBoardActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_notify"
        android:icon="@drawable/mail_icon"
        appmunu:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Notification" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favourite"
        android:icon="@drawable/favourite_icon"
        appmunu:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Favourite" />

    <item
        android:id ="@+id/action_navigation"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu"
        appmunu:showAsAction = "always"
        android:title="navigation"
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>
</menu>
```

This is my TabhostActivity

```
public class TabHostActivity extends TabActivity {


    private Context context;
    private static final String TAB_1_TAG = "AboutCollege";
    private static final String TAB_2_TAG = "Focus of Course";
    private static final String TAB_3_TAG = "Admision";
    private static final String TAB_4_TAG = "Contact Details";
    private static final String TAB_5_TAG = "Back";

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityStarted();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityContext(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityStoped();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityStarted();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityStoped();
    }
//here this the code for displaying the actionbar
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_user_dash_boad, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // delete the selected event from event list added here
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_notify:
                return true;

            case R.id.action_favourite:
                return true;
            case R.id.action_navigation:

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_host);
         context = getApplicationContext();
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        TabHost.TabSpec tag5= tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_5_TAG);
        TabHost.TabSpec tag4= tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_4_TAG);
        TabHost.TabSpec tag3= tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_3_TAG);
        TabHost.TabSpec tag2= tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_2_TAG);
        TabHost.TabSpec tag1= tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_1_TAG);
        tag1.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.college_hover)).setContent(new Intent(this,AdmissionActivity.class));
        tag2.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.course)).setContent(new Intent(this, AboutCollegeActivity.class));
        tag3.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.admission)).setContent(new Intent(this, AboutCollegeActivity.class));
        tag4.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.contact)).setContent(new Intent(this, AboutCollegeActivity.class));
        tag5.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back)).setContent(new Intent(this, AboutCollegeActivity.class));
        tabHost.addTab(tag1);
        tabHost.addTab(tag2);
        tabHost.addTab(tag3);
        tabHost.addTab(tag4);



    }
}
```

In here Actionbar dosn't displayed but all other activites other than TabhostActivity it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Define a private variable of appcompatActivity first like these

```
private AppCompatActivity myact;
```

then add below lines inside your oncreate method

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    myact.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

for api's below level 11

```
myact.getActionBar(toolbar);
```

I think this should solve the problem.See the root cause of this problem is your class is extending TabActivity not AppcompatActivity or Activity.So we have to specifically mention whether to show the Actionbar or not. I would recommend to use the Android Studio's  standard Tabsliderview to design your application it is much easier to use and is well structured.

Comment: if i add that line i got the null pointer exception on that line

Comment: which version of the support library are you using?which platform are using eclipse or studio?

Comment: i am using android studio suupport library v7